# sql statement - relationship between two tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access, ado

I have two tables in access:
Messages which has :

- MessageID
- MessageFrom
- MessageTO
- MessageSubject
- Messages

User which has

- UserID
- Username
- Password

.
Those two tables have a relationship between UserID and MessageTO.

My user connects and I have to check if it's the right login / password in my database. THEN I need to display informations from both tables.
I am not sure how to join them.

```
<%  
var mycon;
mycon = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var myrec = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"); 
mycon.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Omnivox.mdb"); 

var txtpassword = Request.QueryString("txtpassword");
var txtuserID = parseInt (Request.QueryString("txtuserID"));
  if (txtpassword == "" || txtuserID == "")
{
    Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
}

sql= "SELECT * FROM UserOmnivox WHERE UserID=" +txtuserID+ " AND UserPassword='" + txtpassword + "';";    
var sql;
myrec. Open (sql, mycon);   

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

tb_Message table with sample data

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| MessageID | MessageFrom | MessageTo | MessageSubject | Message      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| 1         | 1           | 2         | Test Subject   | Test Message |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
```

tb_User table with sample data

```
+--------+----------+----------+
| UserID | UserName | Password |
+--------+----------+----------+
| 1      | User1    | 1234     |
+--------+----------+----------+
| 2      | User2    | 4321     |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

Considering above data structure, below query may help you to pull the data -

```
SELECT M.MessageID, U1.UserName AS MessageFrom, U2.UserName AS MessageTo, M.MessageSubject, M.Message
FROM (tb_Message M
INNER JOIN tb_Users U1 ON M.MessageFrom = U1.UserID)
INNER JOIN tb_Users U2 ON M.MessageTo = U2.UserID
```

This will show result as -

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| MessageID | MessageFrom | MessageTo | MessageSubject | Message      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| 1         | User1       | User2     | Test Subject   | Test Message |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uses `JOINS`, in this case you query could be (It's an example with some of the columns): 
`SELECT U.username, U.password, M.messages 
FROM User U INNER JOIN Message M ON U.UserID=M.MessageTO`

You have to use **alias** to reference to table User (U) or Message (M), and add the `JOIN` on the condition, that means the columns with the relationship.

PD: It's a good practice use words in **singular** in the table names, not plural.

Answer (score 0):

Your join query would basically be

```
Select M.MessageFrom, M.MessageTO, M.MessageSubject
FROM Messages M
INNER JOIN User U
ON M.MessageTO = U.UserID;
```

However, there is more to fix here. You should use [paramterized queries](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ms%20access%20parameterized%20query%20asp.net%20webforms) instead of string concatenation. You are currently vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20injection)

I am also curious as to why I see <% in your code. This leads me to believe that I am looking at an aspx file instead of an aspx.cs file. This code should be in a file that ends in .cs

Having said that, I do not have a ton of webforms experience, nor do I have many reputation points. My answer may not be exactly what you need, but hopefully the links will be of some assistance.